# Getting error while converting to pandas dataframe from a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a list of values to a dataframe in a single row so the output should be a pandas dataframe with single row but getting `object of type 'int' has no len()`
I tried other SO posts but same error.

```
metadata  = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'], data=metadata)
```

Comment: Use  `data=[metadata]`

Comment: `metadata` should be `metadata  = [[var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

metadata  = ["var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5"]

arr = np.array(metadata).reshape(1,5)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'], data = arr)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas expects the `data` argument to be a nested array where rows of the array contain data mapping the the `columns` specified. Update your code to be like so:

```
metadata  = [[var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]] # nested array for pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3, col4', 'col5'], data=metadata)
```